# UIView Background color is not same as like navigationBar in swift4

Tags: ios, swift

I have used navigationBar bar background color in swift. I add UIView bellow navigationBar & add background color.But i have used same color both. What is the wrong with the code.here is my image

[image]

Here is my  view controller code..

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
 @IBOutlet weak var title_view: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //set uiview backgorund
      title_view.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x1f62af)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0xFFFFFF)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x1f62af);
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
  }
}
```

title_view background color is different from navigationBar. But I have used same color both of them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any chance your navigation bar is translucent? Try to add:

`self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false` and see if the colors are the same after that.